# ATMega chips come with the Arduino bootloader

Tags: atmega, bootloader, arduino

Do the Arduino Duemilanove USB Board with Atmega328 come with the Arduino bootloader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - all boards with ATMega labelled Arduino come with the bootloader. Individual chips will say specifically, generaly if ordered from an Arduino supplier then they will have bootloader, whilst if ordered from generic electronic supplier they will not.

Comment: If they don't have a bootloader, what do you require to burn one in?

Comment: You just need an AVR programmer. Either ISP (supports all AVR's) or JTAG (supports most). This could be as simple as a parallel port programmer -- build it yourself with a couple resistors and diodes...or you could order a fancy AVRISP MKII USB programmer.

Comment: Like the mega-isp?

Comment: mega isp is great is you already have an Ardunio with bootloader and want to load the bootloader into another chip. Also consider tinyusb (http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=16&products_id=46 ), connects to usb port and can program AVR chips from PC.